# Swap only the first character of two strings

Tags: c

```
char *a="gizzzzz";
char *b="figantic";
void swap(char **ptr1,char **ptr2){
    char temp = **ptr1;
    **ptr1    = **ptr2;
    **ptr2    =   temp;
}
```

now I wish to swap only first character so that I get "fizzzz" and "gigantic"
please help

Comment: Your strings are literals, you can't modify them.

Comment: Any reasons you pass "pointers to pointers" instead of just pointers?

Comment: I was learning how to swap strings and then I came across swapping of strings using pointers to pointers
so I thought of using it for my problem as well

Answer (score 0):

You are passing constant strings, which are stored in read only memory. You need to allocate the strings like this

```
char a[] = "gizzzzz", b[] = "figantic";
swap(a, b);

void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
    char tmp;

    tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

Comment: `swap(&a, &b);` should be `swap(a, b);`

Comment: but 
 
swap(&a, &b); swap(a, b);
both are working same
am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Sam no.  C is doing something wrong.   It's a schizoid language that, often, treats arrays, and pointers to them, in the same way, as if they were the same thing, (which they are NOT).

Comment: fixed @kaylum [15 chars]

Comment: Detail: "... constant strings, which are stored in read only memory" --> they _might_ be stored in read-only memory.   Writing to a string literals is undefined behavior.